# Problems calling $.getJSON from SharePoint's Content Editor Web Part

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, odata, getjson

I have a very simple piece of jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://www.blahblah.com/ScriptingResourceCenter/ResourcesjQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var qry = "http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/"
        $.getJSON(qry, function (result, status) {
            alert(status);
        });
});
</script>
```

This is located in a Content Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2007. When I run the above script on my local machine it load fine, in fact any .getJSON query works, but once I move this into the Web Part I get nothing. The status is not even returned. I do know that the jQuery loads because I've put in an alert statement just before the JSON call and it executes fine. What could be the problem? I get no error message, no indication what is wrong.
I'm using jQuery 1.4.1
SharePoint 2007
Any assistance will be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure this runs in localhost? when your own domain doesn't match the domain in which you are running this error happens in background: XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
"http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/. Origin http://yourdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." that means that you are trying to do a cross-domain request.

Comment: This runs on localhost, 100%. I'm not actually trying to get data from netflix, I have my own service that also runs on localhost, but fails to run on SharePoint. In all the cases I have allowed cross-domin requests. I'm only using netflix here to take out another unknown from the equation.

Comment: I am not so familiar to this but I think SharePoint needs some kind of library to use jQuery, not the simple one (correct me if I am wrong) but take a look at this http://jpoint.codeplex.com/ that is a jQuery  just for SharePoint.

Comment: @OscarJara, thanks, but I believe that is more if you'd like to manipulate forms, lists, etc on SharePoint itself. I'm interested in getting some data outside of SharePoint.

Comment: I changed my call from .getJSON to .ajax, now I'm getting the following error, and no matter from where I try to pull the jqyery file, the error is always the same. What can I do regarding this Access Denied?
Message: Access is denied.
Line: 125
Char: 88
Code: 0
URI: ://www.blahblah.com/IT_Global/SoftwareDevelopers/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.4.1.min.js

Comment: You got the cross-domain request error?

Comment: @OscarJara I get an Access Denied error in jquery on line 4984 `// Open the socket
  // Passing null username, generates a login popup on Opera (#2865)
  if ( s.username ) {
   xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password);
  } else {
   xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async);
  }`